# How to fix excluded URLs after website was hacked

Tags: seo, google-search-console, google-search, googlebot

My website was hacked a while back and google managed to index millions of pages with hacked content.

I have requested the removal of pages that Google indexed and still waiting for removal. However, I have a few million pages that google crawled and yet to index. 99% of those are in need of removal and I don't know how to.

Is there anything can be done about this?

p.p.s the only thing that sprint to my mind is changing 404 to 410, but I have no idea on how long it may take to get rid of those millions of crawled pages.

p.s. most of those pages have randomised page names such as `9cwp8wj6328efb`

[image: Excluded Pages]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should put it in 410.
You after just need to wait, if you have the url list and want to accelerate the process, you can add all those Url in a specific new Url (like : recrawl-test.html) and force index of this file in the search console.
Wait a few time and remove also this recrawl-test.html

Comment: I finally understood what you meant by adding all those URLs into a single page... I may have to try that out! 2mil of links is definitely a lot!

Comment: If you have the full list on an excel sheet for example, I suggest you to use the concat function to generate each line of the file quickly.